# no affect on CORS enabling with NESTJS

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs

I fail to enable the CORS for testing with the latest NestJS 8.0.6 and a fresh http + ws project. That said, I want to see the  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the servers response (so that the client would accept it).      Here is my main.ts where I've tried 3 approches: 1) with options, 2) with a method, 3) with app.use. None of them works.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { microserviceConfig} from "./msKafkaConfig";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true}); // DOESN'T WORK
  app.enableCors(); // DOESN'T WORK

  app.connectMicroservice(microserviceConfig);
  await app.startAllMicroservices();

  
  // DOESN'T WORK
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,UPGRADE,CONNECT,TRACE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });
  
  await app.listen(3000);



}
bootstrap();
```

Please, do NOT give me a lesson on how dangerous CORS (XSForgery) is if we accept all domains. there is enough material about that. And I'm well aware of it. This is about NestJS not replying the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` element in the header.

The browser console reports:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nm4kVQ1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the chrome header inspection I see:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nm4kUZ-
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 97
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2021 19:41:05 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
EIO: 4
transport: polling
t: Nm4kUZ-
```

Does the `Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin` have an influence?

(btw, it works just fine with a simple express setup. So it cannot be my browser's fault.)

Comment: Not to be insulting, but because a lot of people make this mistake, Have you inspected the response in your network console to determine what exactly the response is rather than stopping at the CORS error? what *exactly* is the cors error? How does websocket come into play here?

Comment: I just tested with `curl` and `{ cors: true }` and `app.enableCors()`. Both of these options resulted in having a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Not sure what you're running into, but it doesn't seem to be the fault of the framework

Comment: @KevinB I don't think the websocket should have any affect. After all it's just an http upgrade - just pointing out.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel True. I've checked that too. (I've added CORS after I've added a Kafka Producer and Consumer. Maybe I messed up something there). Anyhow, thanks for confirming.

Comment: That URL looks like a Socket.IO connection URL. Do you have the CORS options enabled for the gateway? `@WebsocketGateway({ cors: '*:*' })`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel can your last reply as the answer so I can mark it. Jjjj... I totally missed the decorator's options - and thus the websocket own CORS settings. thanks heaps. Saved me hours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `enableCors` and `{ cors: true }` options are for the HTTP server (express or fastify). The URL given showing the CORS error came from a socket.io connection. To enable CORS for `socket.io` you need to use the options in the `@WebsocketGateway()` decorator, like

```js
@WebsocketGateway({ cors: '*:*' })
export class FooGateway {}
```

Make sure to have both the host and the port set for the websocket cors as `host:port`

Answer (score 2):

I deleted or changed **transports** argument in the array. It is from the frontend

```
    //FRONTEND FILE
    socket = io(BE_URL, {
      withCredentials: true,
      query: {
        token,
        isUserNew,
      },
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'], // USE ['polling', 'websocket'] OR DELETED IT
      autoConnect: false,
    });



//BACKEND FILE
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: { credentials: true, methods: ['GET', 'POST'], origin: ['http://host1', 'http://host2']},
  transports: ['polling', 'websocket'],
})
```

I read it - https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#transports

> One possible downside is that the validity of your CORS configuration will only be checked if the WebSocket connection fails to be established.

I really hope this answer saves you some time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently 
and fixed it as the following
in main.ts

```
in main.ts

    // import
    import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

    //in bootstrap() function
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
    app.enableCors();
    app.setGlobalPrefix('/api/v1')
```

```
//in your Gateway service 

import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';
import {
    OnGatewayConnection,
    OnGatewayDisconnect,
    OnGatewayInit,
    SubscribeMessage,
    WebSocketGateway,
    WebSocketServer,
} from "@nestjs/websockets";
@WebSocketGateway(
    {
        path: "/api/v1/ws",
        serveClient: false,
        cors: {
            origin: `*`
        }
    })
export class AppGateway
    implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    
    private logger: Logger = new Logger(AppGateway.name);

    ...
    afterInit(server: Server) {
        this.logger.log(`Init`);
    }

    handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
        this.logger.log(`handleDisconnect: ${client.id}`);
        this.wss.socketsLeave(client.id);
    }

    handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
        this.wss.socketsJoin(client.id)
        this.logger.log(`handleConnection: ${client.id}`);
    }
}
```

```
   //in your client side 

 this.socket = io("ws://localhost:3000", 
       {
        path: "/api/v1/ws",
        reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
       }
);
```

```
// package.json
  "dependencies": { 
  "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^8.0.6",
  "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
  "@nestjs/websockets": "^6.1.0"
},
 "devDependencies": {
  "@types/socket.io": "^3.0.2",
  "@types/ws": "^7.4.7"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It helps me with cors problem.